# Visual Studio Code - printf, scanf, perror, etc - red squiggly underlines

Tags: mingw, visual-studio-code

Despite my code compiling and executing fine, the first occurrences of printf, scanf, perror, etc (i.e members of stdio.h) have red squiggly underlines, as does stdio.h itself. Why does my code compile if Visual Studio Code cannot find stdio.h?

If that is the reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSC doesn't have its own compiler per say. Everything is done via build scripts and project files. I imagine that you need to adjust the code editor (addin) to point to the same location where you store the header files so it can find them when editing. It seems that if everything builds correctly, then the compiler is already able to find these files.